# Require Waving flag effect over iOS application

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, ripple

There is a requirement in my application to wave a flag image like air blowing.

I have found one similar effect - Ripple Effect. But it is specifically for water ripple. Means, it gives kinda same effect like air blow but the problem with this is, it automatically affects from the center of the view, Whereas air blowing happens in left to right manner.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: WrightsCS: I have found RippleEffect but it is not fulfilling my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you'd desire, but you could either

a) use a movie with a waving flag as a background for your view

b) animate a series of images with a waving flag as a background for your view

c) you could try some OpenGL, this tutorial seems useful: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/flag_effect_(waving_texture)/16002/

Comment: Sorry to say but i am not that much used to with OpenGL so i am not getting how to integrate that code to mine.

Comment: @Mrunal Any you found for iOS related to wave flag effect?

Comment: @SaumilShah I had to use set of images (array) and create a gif effect.

Comment: @Mrunal Thanks for reply.